# How to create multiple shortcuts at application start

Tags: ios, swift, swift4.2, nsuseractivity

So what I am trying is to donate multiple shortcuts (like 20 types of activites) at app delegate...it is weird that it works if I donate in a specific view controller, but if I make a for loop in a app delegate it doesnt work...here is the code:

```
activity = NSUserActivity(activityType: activityType)

        activity?.title = activityTitle

        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {

            activity?.suggestedInvocationPhrase = suggestedPhrase

            activity?.isEligibleForPrediction = true

            activity?.persistentIdentifier = NSUserActivityPersistentIdentifier(activityType)

        }

        activity?.isEligibleForSearch = true



        //self.activities.append(activity!)

        if #available(iOS 12.0, *) {

            NSUserActivity.deleteSavedUserActivities(withPersistentIdentifiers: [activityType], completionHandler: {[weak self] in

                self?.activity?.becomeCurrent()

            })

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Appdelegate is the first thing that's run on app load, this can cause it not to load your shortcuts, consider running them from the first viewcontroller the app opens